# CCActionFollow will not follow the target object and scroll layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, ccaction

I have a ball object that falls straight down a level made in SpriteBuilder as a layer. The level is added to the gameplay scene, which has a ccnode (_levelNode) as a child of the physics node. However, when the game runs it either doesn't scroll, or the view is messed up.

My code is:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
//_physicsNode.debugDraw = TRUE;

_loadedLevel = [CCBReader load:@"levels/Level1" owner:self];
[_levelNode addChild: _loadedLevel];

}

- (void)onEnter {
[super onEnter];

self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
self.isGamePaused = FALSE;

_followBall = [CCActionFollow actionWithTarget:_ball worldBoundary:[_loadedLevel boundingBox]];
[_physicsNode runAction:_followBall];

}
```

Comment: You should not be running the action on your `physics node`. Try running it on your content level node.

Comment: I've tried running it on _levelNode, _loadedLevel, self, and _physicsNode. None of them work correctly, though I do get minor different results

Comment: Could you post a zip with your project or a smaller demo project that illustrates the problem so I can take a more detailed look?

Comment: I tried multiple things that each should have worked and had multiple people look at it. I've decided to use my own scroll instead.